# The node process stops waiting for data from the database server

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

There are several DB queries that take a long time to complete (from 1 sec to several minutes).
Queries: A call to a stored procedure where the SQL query is being assembled and REF_CURSOR is returned to the OUT variable.

In simplified form it looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE selectSomeDate(res out sys_refcursor)
IS
BEGIN
  open res for 'select x from dual'; -- It takes several minutes to complete
END;
```

To interact with the Oracle DBMS, the oracledb library is used

There is such a simple code (in a very simplified format)

```
async function getConnect() {
  conn = await oradb.getConnection(); // get connect
  opts.outFormat = oradb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;
  opts.prefetchRows = 100; // try set to 0, try remove
  opts.resultSet = true; // try set to false, try remove
  const result = await conn.execute(sqltext, binds, opts); // execute
  return result;
}
```

There is a function that extracts data from the cursor. SQLStatement is a return from the getConnect function

```
async function getData(sqlStatement) {
  const connect = sqlStatement.conn; 
  const cursor = await sqlStatement.result.outBinds.result; 
  // try read data
  const res =  await cursor.getRows(); // <- here frozen
  await cursor.close().catch(e => { 
    logger.error(msg(`Ошибка закрытия курсора ${e}`, printStackTrace(e)));
  });
  await connect.close().catch(e => { 
    logger.error(msg(`Ошибка закрытия соединения ${e}`, printStackTrace(e)));
  });
  return res;
}
```

OUTBIND variable(*sqlStatement.result.outBinds.result*) declared:

```
result: { type: oradb.CURSOR, dir: oradb.BIND_OUT },
```

The environment variable UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=100 is set

I can't understand why when waiting for data from the server (read as waiting for a query to be executed in SQL), the JS node process freezes. 
Everywhere in the docks and manuals it is written, do so and you will be happy. There are no "clarifications" on waiting for data, there are no warnings that something in the node may be blocked.

If you send requests in batches, everything will stop right there. If the request is sent to 1, then the process will stop in N seconds (Apparently something is scoring somewhere - only that's what it could be ...)

After receiving a response from the database, everything continues to work successfully and smartly.
During the "hang", the node does not respond to any network requests, and the output to the console also stops.

Perhaps someone has encountered this? Which way to dig and what to look at?

nodejs server 14.17, Oracle database 19, Oracle client 12.2

UPD: 
"Fading" occurs when nodejs receives the cursor, but the execution of the SQL request itself continues. As soon as the SQL query is executed and the data arrives, the node js process continues to work. It seems that while waiting for data, node js continuously polls the database. At this point, the load on the database grows in terms of CPU consumption. When starting the procedure from the database, there is no such load.

Comment: With async code, a full testcase is useful. But check that there is no DB lock preventing some SQL from completing. Check the [pool stats](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-pool-monitoring) to see if you have some connection leak. Make sure UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE is not being reset if you have some scripts or tooling that is invoking Node.js.  Set prefetchRows to 0, see https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/oracledb.html#oracledb.prefetchRows depending how rows are generated

Comment: @ChristopherJones Pool is OK. The error is reproduced on 1 single request. UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE in pool_stat show 100. prefetchRows was set to 0 and 100. The procedure is called, we get the cursor. We are waiting for data from the cursor. Getting the data. While waiting for the data, the node js process stops working and does not respond. As the data is received, everything continues. I am in some confusion from this behavior

Comment: Keep debugging and tracing. Triple check.  It's not easily feasible to debug via SO comments.  It might be better to discuss on GitHub, but fundamentally you'll need to identify what the app is doing and why.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I solved the problem by rewriting the code to use DBMS_SQL.return_result and implicitResults. However, my research led to the [problem of analyzing a long query in the database when filtering data by transferred collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771807/why-is-it-that-when-filtering-by-two-collections-the-execution-time-increases-s)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the example above didn't work. Never unearthed

I rewrote the SQL procedure and the data sampling script on the node js side and it worked

We change the procedure using the DBMS_SQL package (We remove the res variable from the out procedure parameters and declare it in the procedure itself):

```
PROCEDURE selectSomeDate()
IS
res sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  open res for 'select x from dual'; -- It takes several minutes to complete
  DBMS_SQL.return_result(res);
END;
```

In node js, we change getting data from the outbind variable to implicitResults:

```
async function getData(sqlStatement) {
  const connect = sqlStatement.conn; 
  const cursor = await sqlStatement.implicitResults[0]; 
  // try read data
  const res =  await cursor.getRows(); // <- here not frozen
  await cursor.close().catch(e => { 
    logger.error(msg(`Error close cursor ${e}`, printStackTrace(e)));
  });
  await connect.close().catch(e => { 
    logger.error(msg(`Error close connection ${e}`, printStackTrace(e)));
  });
  return res;
}
```

After that, the node js process stopped freezing while waiting for data.