# Why is it that when filtering by two collections, the execution time increases significantly and the query takes a very long time?

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

**Given:** A table with 6 million records. We need to collect some statistics for the quarter. 650 thousand lines fall into the quarter. 
The data filtering parameters come into the procedure. Some of them are transmitted as an "array".

In the products and categories fields, for example, there are only 30 unique values (in reality 27 and 22).

There is a data type(collection):

```
create or replace type strings is table of varchar2(256);
```

Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE getData(
  Filter1 IN VARCHAR2, 
  Filter2 IN VARCHAR2, 
  Filter3 IN strings,
  Filter4 IN strings,
  RES OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) IS
 tSQL: CLOB;
  b1 strings;
  b2 strings;
  bindNum number := 0;
  BEGIN
    tSQL := 'SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable t WHERE to_char(t.dateInsert, 'Q.YYYY') = to_char(sysdate, 'Q.YYYY') ';
    
    IF (Filter3 IS NOT NULL) THEN
      tSQl := tSQL || ' AND nvl(products, 'notProduct') IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(:b1)) ';
      b1 := Filter3;
      bindNum := bindNum + 1;
    END IF;

    IF (Filter4 IS NOT NULL) THEN
      tSQl := tSQL || ' AND nvl(categories, 'notCateg') IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(:b2)) ';
      b2 := Filter4;
      bindNum := bindNum + 1;
    END IF;
    
    IF (bindNum = 1) then
      OPEN res FOR tSQL USING b1;
    elsif (bindNum = 2) then
      OPEN res FOR tSQL USING b1, b2;
    ELSE
      OPEN res FOR tSQL;
    END IF;
    
  END;
```

If you perform the procedure without data, i.e. with a filter for the current quarter, the request is executed in 2-3 seconds.

Let's add filter3 to the parameters with the number of elements in the collection 28 (out of 30 unique across the entire table) - the query works out in 2-3 seconds

Let's remove filter3 and add filter4 to the parameters with the number of elements in the collection of 28 (out of 30 unique throughout the table) - the query works out in 2-3 seconds

Let's execute the request with the passed filter3 and filter4 with filling of 28 elements in each collection and the request works out in **3-5 minutes**!

OK, maybe something with the data and statistics on the table, we write a query manually and change the selection from the collection to an enumeration of incoming values into `IN

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE to_char(dateInsert, 'Q.YYYY') = to_char(sysdate, 'Q.YYYY')
AND nvl(products, 'notProduct') IN ('prod1', 'prod2', ...) 
AND nvl(categories, 'notCateg') IN ('categ1', 'categ2', ...)
```

The request is processed in 2-3 seconds...

> **How does this happen?**

Why is the selection by date and by one of the filters by collection performed quickly, and by two collections performed orders of magnitude longer? And why doesn't this happen if you replace `SELECT COLUMN_VALUE from table(collection)` on an explicit enumeration of values?

Oracle OEM monitoring shows high CPU consumption.

*I understand with my head that the problem lies somewhere on the surface and is clearly related to the work of collections inside queries, but I can't understand... It seems that with two collections, either some kind of data lock occurs for the object, or it somehow begins to re-read the values from the collection many times for each row...*

#### Execution plan

```
20  | Id  | Operation                                    | Name                  | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
21  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22  |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                             |                       |        |       | 12808 (100)|          |       |       |          |
23  |   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                               |                       |      2 |  3246 | 12808   (1)| 00:00:01 |   686K|   686K|          |
24  |*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER                            |                       |      2 |  3246 | 12807   (1)| 00:00:01 |   995K|   995K|  749K (0)|
25  |*  3 |    HASH JOIN OUTER                           |                       |      2 |  2214 | 12793   (1)| 00:00:01 |  1020K|  1020K|  742K (0)|
26  |   4 |     VIEW                                     |                       |      2 |  2154 | 12786   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
27  |   5 |      HASH GROUP BY                           |                       |      2 |  2128 | 12786   (1)| 00:00:01 |   867K|   867K|          |
28  |   6 |       VIEW                                   |                       |      2 |  2128 | 12785   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
29  |   7 |        UNION-ALL                             |                       |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
30  |   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                         |                       |      1 |    66 |  1113   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
31  |   9 |          MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                |                       |      1 |     4 |    59   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
32  |  10 |           SORT UNIQUE                        |                       |      1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2048 |  2048 |          |
33  |* 11 |            COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH |                       |      1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
34  |  12 |           BUFFER SORT                        |                       |      1 |     2 |    30   (4)| 00:00:01 |  2048 |  2048 |          |
35  |  13 |            SORT UNIQUE                       |                       |      1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2048 |  2048 |          |
36  |* 14 |             COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH|                       |      1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
37  |* 15 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | CLOSED_DEALS          |      1 |    62 |  1054   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
38  |* 16 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | IDX_DC_DEALDATEQ      |  12687 |       |    41   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
39  |  17 |         NESTED LOOPS                         |                       |      1 |    48 | 11672   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
40  |  18 |          MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                |                       |      1 |     4 |    59   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
41  |  19 |           SORT UNIQUE                        |                       |      1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2048 |  2048 |          |
42  |* 20 |            COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH |                       |      1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
43  |  21 |           BUFFER SORT                        |                       |      1 |     2 |    30   (4)| 00:00:01 |  2048 |  2048 |          |
44  |  22 |            SORT UNIQUE                       |                       |      1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |  2048 |  2048 |          |
45  |* 23 |             COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH|                       |      1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
46  |* 24 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | DEALS                 |      3 |   132 | 11613   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
47  |* 25 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | IDX_D_CREATDATEQ      |  52206 |       |   285   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
48  |  26 |     VIEW                                     |                       |     32 |   960 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
49  |  27 |      UNION-ALL                               |                       |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
50  |  28 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                      | SPR_PRODUCTS          |     19 |   513 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
51  |  29 |       HASH UNIQUE                            |                       |     13 |   403 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |  1034K|  1034K|          |
52  |  30 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | SPR_PRODUCTS_DECODE   |     13 |   403 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
53  |  31 |    VIEW                                      |                       |     48 | 24768 |    14  (22)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
54  |  32 |     SORT UNIQUE                              |                       |     48 |  3823 |    14  (22)| 00:00:01 |  4096 |  4096 |          |
55  |  33 |      UNION-ALL                               |                       |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
56  |* 34 |       HASH JOIN ANTI NA                      |                       |     32 |  2848 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |   958K|   958K| 1294K (0)|
57  |  35 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | SPR_TECHNOLOGY        |     32 |  2176 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
58  |  36 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | SPR_TECHNOLOGY_DECODE |     15 |   315 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
59  |  37 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                      | SPR_TECHNOLOGY_DECODE |     15 |   975 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
60  |  38 |       FAST DUAL                              |                       |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
61  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
62   
63  Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
64  -------------------------------------------------------------
65   
66     1 - SEL$5A8733C9
67     4 - SEL$3        / VX@SEL$2
68     5 - SEL$3       
69     6 - SET$1        / GX@SEL$3
70     7 - SET$1       
71     8 - SEL$574ED37E
72    11 - SEL$574ED37E / KOKBF$0@SEL$6
73    14 - SEL$574ED37E / KOKBF$1@SEL$8
74    15 - SEL$574ED37E / CD@SEL$4
75    16 - SEL$574ED37E / CD@SEL$4
76    17 - SEL$72CD2FF1
77    20 - SEL$72CD2FF1 / KOKBF$2@SEL$11
78    23 - SEL$72CD2FF1 / KOKBF$3@SEL$13
79    24 - SEL$72CD2FF1 / CD@SEL$9
80    25 - SEL$72CD2FF1 / CD@SEL$9
81    26 - SET$3        / P@SEL$18
82    27 - SET$3       
83    28 - SEL$19       / PX@SEL$19
84    29 - SEL$20      
85    30 - SEL$20       / D@SEL$20
86    31 - SET$2        / T@SEL$2
87    32 - SET$2       
88    34 - SEL$AC77216A
89    35 - SEL$AC77216A / T@SEL$14
90    36 - SEL$AC77216A / SPR_TECHNOLOGY_DECODE@SEL$15
91    37 - SEL$16       / TD@SEL$16
92    38 - SEL$17       / DUAL@SEL$17
93   
94  Outline Data
95  -------------
96   
97    /*+
98        BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
99        IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
100       OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('19.1.0')
101       DB_VERSION('19.1.0')
102       ALL_ROWS
103       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$574ED37E")
104       UNNEST(@"SEL$8A3193DA")
105       UNNEST(@"SEL$ABDE6DFF")
106       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$72CD2FF1")
107       UNNEST(@"SEL$61262C81")
108       UNNEST(@"SEL$285A8194")
109       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SET$1")
110       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$3")
111       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$AC77216A")
112       UNNEST(@"SEL$15")
113       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$16")
114       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$17")
115       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SET$2")
116       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$19")
117       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$20")
118       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SET$3")
119       OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$5A8733C9")
120       MERGE(@"SEL$E409AC11" >"SEL$1")
121       OUTLINE(@"SEL$4")
122       OUTLINE(@"SEL$8A3193DA")
123       MERGE(@"SEL$8" >"SEL$7")
124       OUTLINE(@"SEL$ABDE6DFF")
125       MERGE(@"SEL$6" >"SEL$5")
126       OUTLINE(@"SEL$9")
127       OUTLINE(@"SEL$61262C81")
128       MERGE(@"SEL$13" >"SEL$12")
129       OUTLINE(@"SEL$285A8194")
130       MERGE(@"SEL$11" >"SEL$10")
131       OUTLINE(@"SEL$14")
132       OUTLINE(@"SEL$15")
133       OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")
134       OUTLINE(@"SEL$E409AC11")
135       MERGE(@"SEL$3B245A68" >"SEL$45368B57")
136       OUTLINE(@"SEL$7")
137       OUTLINE(@"SEL$8")
138       OUTLINE(@"SEL$5")
139       OUTLINE(@"SEL$6")
140       OUTLINE(@"SEL$12")
141       OUTLINE(@"SEL$13")
142       OUTLINE(@"SEL$10")
143       OUTLINE(@"SEL$11")
144       OUTLINE(@"SEL$45368B57")
145       ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$21")
146       OUTLINE(@"SEL$3B245A68")
147       MERGE(@"SEL$1A566D0B" >"SEL$8799457D")
148       OUTLINE(@"SEL$21")
149       OUTLINE(@"SEL$8799457D")
150       ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$DC20D792")
151       OUTLINE(@"SEL$1A566D0B")
152       ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$2")
153       OUTLINE(@"SEL$DC20D792")
154       ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$18")
155       OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")
156       OUTLINE(@"SEL$18")
157       NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$5A8733C9" "VX"@"SEL$2")
158       NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$5A8733C9" "P"@"SEL$18")
159       NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$5A8733C9" "T"@"SEL$2")
160       LEADING(@"SEL$5A8733C9" "VX"@"SEL$2" "P"@"SEL$18" "T"@"SEL$2")
161       USE_HASH(@"SEL$5A8733C9" "P"@"SEL$18")
162       USE_HASH(@"SEL$5A8733C9" "T"@"SEL$2")
163       USE_HASH_AGGREGATION(@"SEL$5A8733C9")
164       NO_ACCESS(@"SEL$3" "GX"@"SEL$3")
165       USE_HASH_AGGREGATION(@"SEL$3")
166       FULL(@"SEL$20" "D"@"SEL$20")
167       USE_HASH_AGGREGATION(@"SEL$20")
168       FULL(@"SEL$19" "PX"@"SEL$19")
169       FULL(@"SEL$16" "TD"@"SEL$16")
170       FULL(@"SEL$AC77216A" "T"@"SEL$14")
171       FULL(@"SEL$AC77216A" "SPR_TECHNOLOGY_DECODE"@"SEL$15")
172       LEADING(@"SEL$AC77216A" "T"@"SEL$14" "SPR_TECHNOLOGY_DECODE"@"SEL$15")
173       USE_HASH(@"SEL$AC77216A" "SPR_TECHNOLOGY_DECODE"@"SEL$15")
174       FULL(@"SEL$72CD2FF1" "KOKBF$2"@"SEL$11")
175       FULL(@"SEL$72CD2FF1" "KOKBF$3"@"SEL$13")
176       INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$72CD2FF1" "CD"@"SEL$9" "IDX_D_CREATDATEQ")
177       BATCH_TABLE_ACCESS_BY_ROWID(@"SEL$72CD2FF1" "CD"@"SEL$9")
178       LEADING(@"SEL$72CD2FF1" "KOKBF$2"@"SEL$11" "KOKBF$3"@"SEL$13" "CD"@"SEL$9")
179       USE_MERGE(@"SEL$72CD2FF1" "KOKBF$3"@"SEL$13")
180       USE_NL(@"SEL$72CD2FF1" "CD"@"SEL$9")
181       SEMI_TO_INNER(@"SEL$72CD2FF1" "KOKBF$2"@"SEL$11")
182       SEMI_TO_INNER(@"SEL$72CD2FF1" "KOKBF$3"@"SEL$13")
183       FULL(@"SEL$574ED37E" "KOKBF$0"@"SEL$6")
184       FULL(@"SEL$574ED37E" "KOKBF$1"@"SEL$8")
185       INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$574ED37E" "CD"@"SEL$4" "IDX_DC_DEALDATEQ")
186       BATCH_TABLE_ACCESS_BY_ROWID(@"SEL$574ED37E" "CD"@"SEL$4")
187       LEADING(@"SEL$574ED37E" "KOKBF$0"@"SEL$6" "KOKBF$1"@"SEL$8" "CD"@"SEL$4")
188       USE_MERGE(@"SEL$574ED37E" "KOKBF$1"@"SEL$8")
189       USE_NL(@"SEL$574ED37E" "CD"@"SEL$4")
190       SEMI_TO_INNER(@"SEL$574ED37E" "KOKBF$0"@"SEL$6")
191       SEMI_TO_INNER(@"SEL$574ED37E" "KOKBF$1"@"SEL$8")
192       END_OUTLINE_DATA
193   */
194  
195 Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
196 ---------------------------------------------------
197  
198    2 - access("T"."TKEY"="VX"."TEHNOLOGY")
199    3 - access("P"."PKEY"="VX"."PRODUCT")
200   11 - filter((VALUE(KOKBF$)<>'CreditPotential' AND VALUE(KOKBF$)<>'Restructuring' AND VALUE(KOKBF$)<>'nullProduct'))
201   14 - filter(VALUE(KOKBF$)<>'ChangeLoan')
202   15 - filter(("SROK">1 AND NVL("TEHNOLOGY",'nullTechnology')=VALUE(KOKBF$) AND NVL("PRODUCT",'nullProduct')=VALUE(KOKBF$) AND CASE  WHEN 
203               ("PRODUCT"='Oborot' AND NVL("TEHNOLOGY",'NotTechnology')='NotTechnology' AND NVL("KISTAGE",(-1))<>(-1)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END =1 AND 
204               "AMOUNT">1 AND NVL("PRODUCT",'nullProduct')<>'Restructuring' AND NVL("PRODUCT",'nullProduct')<>'nullProduct' AND 
205               NVL("PRODUCT",'nullProduct')<>'CreditPotential' AND NVL("TEHNOLOGY",'nullTechnology')<>'ChangeLoan'))
206   16 - access("CD"."SYS_NC00074$"='1.2023')
207   20 - filter((VALUE(KOKBF$)<>'CreditPotential' AND VALUE(KOKBF$)<>'Restructuring' AND VALUE(KOKBF$)<>'nullProduct'))
208   23 - filter(VALUE(KOKBF$)<>'ChangeLoan')
209   24 - filter((NVL("TEHNOLOGY",'nullTechnology')=VALUE(KOKBF$) AND NVL("PRODUCT",'nullProduct')=VALUE(KOKBF$) AND CASE  WHEN 
210               ("PRODUCT"='Oborot' AND NVL("TEHNOLOGY",'NotTechnology')='NotTechnology' AND NVL("KISTAGE",(-1))<>(-1)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END =1 AND "SROK">1 
211               AND "AMOUNT">1 AND NVL("PRODUCT",'nullProduct')<>'Restructuring' AND NVL("TEHNOLOGY",'nullTechnology')<>'ChangeLoan' AND 
212               NVL("PRODUCT",'nullProduct')<>'CreditPotential' AND NVL("PRODUCT",'nullProduct')<>'nullProduct'))
213   25 - access("CD"."SYS_NC00076$"='1.2023')
214   34 - access("T"."TKEY"="TOLDKEY")
215  
216 Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
217 -----------------------------------------------------------
218  
219    1 - "VX"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], NVL("P"."PGROUP",'Нет продукта')[512], 
220        NVL("T"."TGROUP",'Нет технологии')[512], "VX"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,1024], "VX"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], SUM("VX"."AMSUM")[22], 
221        SUM("VX"."CNT")[22]
222    2 - (#keys=1) "VX"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "VX"."AMSUM"[NUMBER,22], 
223        "P"."PGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512], "VX"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,1024], "VX"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."CNT"[NUMBER,22], "T"."TGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512]
224    3 - (#keys=1) "VX"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "VX"."AMSUM"[NUMBER,22], 
225        "VX"."TEHNOLOGY"[VARCHAR2,1024], "VX"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,1024], "VX"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."CNT"[NUMBER,22], 
226        "P"."PGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512]
227    4 - "VX"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "VX"."PRODUCT"[VARCHAR2,1024], 
228        "VX"."TEHNOLOGY"[VARCHAR2,1024], "VX"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,1024], "VX"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], "VX"."CNT"[NUMBER,22], 
229        "VX"."AMSUM"[NUMBER,22]
230    5 - "GX"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "GX"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22], "GX"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "GX"."PRODUCT"[VARCHAR2,1024], 
231        "GX"."TEHNOLOGY"[VARCHAR2,1024], "GX"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,1024], "GX"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], COUNT(*)[22], SUM("GX"."AMOUNT")[22]
232    6 - "GX"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "GX"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22], "GX"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "GX"."PRODUCT"[VARCHAR2,1024], 
233        "GX"."TEHNOLOGY"[VARCHAR2,1024], "GX"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,1024], "GX"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], "GX"."AMOUNT"[NUMBER,22]
234    7 - STRDEF[22], STRDEF[22], STRDEF[1024], STRDEF[1024], STRDEF[1024], STRDEF[1024], STRDEF[22], STRDEF[22]
235    8 - "CD"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "CD"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,1024], "PRODUCT"[VARCHAR2,1024], "TEHNOLOGY"[VARCHAR2,1024], 
236        "AMOUNT"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22]
237    9 - VALUE(KOKBF$)[256], VALUE(KOKBF$)[256]
238   10 - (#keys=1) VALUE(KOKBF$)[256]
239   11 - VALUE(A0)[256]
240   12 - (#keys=0) VALUE(KOKBF$)[256]
241   13 - (#keys=1) VALUE(KOKBF$)[256]
242   14 - VALUE(A0)[256]
243   15 - "CD"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "CD"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,1024], "PRODUCT"[VARCHAR2,1024], "TEHNOLOGY"[VARCHAR2,1024], 
244        "AMOUNT"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22]
245   16 - "CD".ROWID[ROWID,10], "CD"."SYS_NC00074$"[VARCHAR2,6]
246   17 - "CD"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "PRODUCT"[VARCHAR2,1024], "TEHNOLOGY"[VARCHAR2,1024], "AMOUNT"[NUMBER,22], 
247        "CD"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22]
248   18 - VALUE(KOKBF$)[256], VALUE(KOKBF$)[256]
249   19 - (#keys=1) VALUE(KOKBF$)[256]
250   20 - VALUE(A0)[256]
251   21 - (#keys=0) VALUE(KOKBF$)[256]
252   22 - (#keys=1) VALUE(KOKBF$)[256]
253   23 - VALUE(A0)[256]
254   24 - "CD"."DEALSOURCE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "PRODUCT"[VARCHAR2,1024], "TEHNOLOGY"[VARCHAR2,1024], "AMOUNT"[NUMBER,22], 
255        "CD"."ISAPPROVED"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISCLIENT"[NUMBER,22], "CD"."ISCREDIT"[NUMBER,22]
256   25 - "CD".ROWID[ROWID,10], "CD"."SYS_NC00076$"[VARCHAR2,6]
257   26 - "P"."PKEY"[VARCHAR2,512], "P"."PGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512]
258   27 - STRDEF[512], STRDEF[512]
259   28 - "PX"."PKEY"[VARCHAR2,512], "PX"."PGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512]
260   29 - "D"."PKEY"[VARCHAR2,512], "D"."PGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512]
261   30 - (rowset=119) "D"."PKEY"[VARCHAR2,512], "D"."PGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512]
262   31 - "T"."TKEY"[VARCHAR2,512], "T"."TGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512]
263   32 - (#keys=3) STRDEF[512], STRDEF[1024], STRDEF[512]
264   33 - STRDEF[512], STRDEF[1024], STRDEF[512]
265   34 - (#keys=1) "T"."TKEY"[VARCHAR2,512], "T"."TGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512], "T"."TVALUE"[VARCHAR2,1024]
266   35 - "T"."TKEY"[VARCHAR2,512], "T"."TVALUE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "T"."TGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512]
267   36 - "TOLDKEY"[VARCHAR2,512]
268   37 - "TD"."TKEY"[VARCHAR2,512], "TD"."TVALUE"[VARCHAR2,1024], "TD"."TGROUP"[VARCHAR2,512]
269  
270 Note
271 -----
272    - Warning: basic plan statistics not available. These are only collected when:
273        * hint 'gather_plan_statistics' is used for the statement or
274        * parameter 'statistics_level' is set to 'ALL', at session or system level
275
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for the query with the various different filters.

Comment: `where x in (select ...)` is often the cause of performance problems. You should use joins. Is there a reason you're not using joins?

Comment: @Bohemian Because this is not a table as such, but values for filtering. The user has a page where he selects filters to display. I filter by this data. It's not very clear how to use join. Instead of checking the occurrence of values in the transferred collection, do a join on this collection?

Comment: Is `notProduct` ever a value in `b1`?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes. The user can select the value "Not filled"

Comment: @MT0 Added execution plan

Comment: @SwaD There are two issues with the provided execution plan: 1) we do not have anything to compare it to to see how it changes. You need to include (at least) two execution plans, one for the static `IN` list and and one for using collections so that we can compare them; and 2) your execution plan is for a much more complicated query with many joins and you either need to replicate the behaviour in your smaller [MRE] and give the execution plan for that or else give us the DDL statements and query for the actual statement where you've generated the execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment but your query could be written as:

```sql
SELECT count(*) 
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  dateInsert >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'Q')
AND    dateinsert <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'Q'), 3)
AND    (  products   MEMBER OF filter3 
       OR ( products IS NULL AND 'notProduct' MEMBER OF filter3 )
       )
AND    (  categories MEMBER OF filter4
       OR ( categories IS NULL AND 'notCateg' MEMBER OF filter4 )
       )
```

If you compare on `to_char(t.dateInsert, 'Q.YYYY')` or `nvl(products, 'notProduct')` then Oracle will not use an index on `dateInsert`, `products` or `categories` and would need separate function-based indexes on the exact functions you call.

By comparing directly on the column Oracle may be able to use indexes which may improve performance.

---

When you do:

```sql
AND    nvl(products, 'notProduct') IN ('prod1', 'prod2', ...)
```

The SQL engine may be clever enough to recognize whether `'notProduct'` is on the right-hand side of the comparison and if it is not then it can simplify the query to:

```sql
AND    products IN ('prod1', 'prod2', ...)
```

Which could be looked up in an index.

If you do:

```sql
AND nvl(products, 'notProduct') IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(:b1))
```

Then the SQL engine cannot make any assumptions about what is on the right-hand side of the comparison and cannot use an index on `products` and is likely going to resort to a full-table scan. You will need to check the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for your queries.

Comment: index build `create index idx_1 on MyTabl(to_char(dateInsert, 'Q.YYYY'))` and have index on products and categories

Comment: At the end of the day, the optimizer choose an execution plan based on cost. And that cost is based on statistics. So we really need to see the execution plans and cardinalities to see why the optimizer is choosing a suboptimal plan.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly what's going wrong with the execution plan for your queries. As BobC pointed out, the issue is likely related to statistics. There are at least three things you can do to improve the optimizer statistics for your query - **"simplify" the quarter expression**, **sample the collections**, and **create extended statistics for data relationships**.

If these suggestions don't help, then you'll need to start gathering execution plans for the different queries.

### Sample Schema

The below code creates a table pretty similar to the one you described.

```
--drop table MyTable;

create table MyTable
(
    id         number primary key,
    dateInsert date,          -- 6 millions rows, 650K rows per quarter
    products   varchar2(100), -- 22
    categories varchar2(100)  -- 27
);

--Create 6M rows with a data skew pretty close to your tables.
--(Have to add in chunks instead of all at once to avoid "ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation".)
begin
    for i in 0 .. 9 loop
        insert into MyTable
        select
            --Create quarters with 600K rows per quarter.
            rownum + (i * 600000) id,
            --Beginning of this month
            trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
            --Plus i months.
            + (i * (365/4))
            --Plus 1/600,000th of a quarter
            + (level * 365/4 /*days per quarter*/ / 600000) dateInsert,
            'product'  || mod(level, 27) products,
            'category' || mod(level, 27) categories
        from dual
        connect by level <= 600000;
    end loop;
end;
/

commit;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'MYTABLE');
end;
/
```

### Quarter Expression

As MTO pointed out, your date expression may be causing some issues. Although your date expression *looks* simple, converting the column value makes it very difficult for Oracle to estimate the number of rows.

The below example shows an estimate of 60K "Rows" for your existing expression, when the real average is closer to 600K, and different quarters have different values. (As a rule of thumb, try to avoid ever converting dates to strings in expressions. There's almost always a native date expression that can be used instead.)

```
explain plan for
SELECT * FROM MyTable t WHERE to_char(t.dateInsert, 'Q.YYYY') = to_char(sysdate, 'Q.YYYY');

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1015944200
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |         | 60000 |  2050K|  9268   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTABLE | 60000 |  2050K|  9268   (5)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter(TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("T"."DATEINSERT"),'Q.YYYY')=TO_C
              HAR(SYSDATE@!,'Q.YYYY'))
```

By converting to MTO's expression, which is more complicated but does not transform the column, the optimizer makes an almost perfect estimate of 203K rows, compared to the actual value of 203835 rows.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT count(*)
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  dateInsert >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'Q')
AND    dateinsert <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'Q'), 3);

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 3441311250
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |         |     1 |     8 |  9186   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE     |         |     1 |     8 |            |          |
|*  2 |   FILTER            |         |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| MYTABLE |   203K|  1592K|  9186   (5)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmq'),3)>TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmq'
              ))
   3 - filter("DATEINSERT"<ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmq'),3) AND 
              "DATEINSERT">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmq'))
```

### Collections

Although your collections are relatively straight-forward, collections can be infinitely complicated pieces of PL/SQL code. There's no easy way for the optimizer to estimate the number of rows of a collection, so it simply estimates 8168 rows, as you can see in the below explain plan:

```
create or replace type strings is table of varchar2(256);

explain plan for
select * from table(strings('a','b','c'));

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1748000095
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |      |  8168 | 16336 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      |  8168 | 16336 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To fix this, use the `DYNAMIC_SAMPLING` hint. This is a "good" hint, because it's providing extra information to the optimizer. Normally, it would be insanely expensive for Oracle to sample rows from every table in every SQL statement in order to estimate the total number of rows. But in this case, since the statement is already running for at least 2 seconds, and the tables involved are just memory structures, that extra sampling time is worth the effort. With this hint, the "Rows" estimate is a perfect guess - 3.

```
explain plan for
select /*+ dynamic_sampling(3) */ * from table(strings('a','b','c'));

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1748000095
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |      |     3 |     6 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      |     3 |     6 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=3)
```

### Data Relationships

If there's an unusual relationship between your products and categories, you may need to gather statistics on the two columns together.

Oracle typically estimates each expression independently. For example, if the query had `PRODUCTS = 'P1' AND CATEGORIES = 'C1'`, Oracle would estimate both cardinalities and multiple them together. So, if each had a 10% chance of being correct, Oracle would multiply them and assume the expression only returns 1% of the rows.

But if C1 and P1 always go together, the true value should be 10% instead of 1%. To give Oracle this information, create [extended statistics](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/post/extended-statistics) on the columns PRODUCTS AND CATEGORIES.

```
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(user, 'MYTABLE', '(PRODUCTS, CATEGORIES)') from dual;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'MYTABLE');
end;
/
```